# Is it possible to make a mbr legacy bootcamp win 10 from a gpt partitioned catalina hdd 10.15.7 with bootcamp 6?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, driver, disk-format, efi

I tried to install win10 to ssd via efi boot on my macbook air 2012, it ran pretty well as far as performance, but because it's pre-uefi it makes it the garbage windows version with no sound, no proper graphics card, can't change brightness, it's awful, then I tried parallels, and I can tell already that it's going to suck how the mouse moves so that's out.

So, my only option is to try a legacy bootcamp partition install somehow sharing the same hdd as my macOS (which has plenty of room and is fast), but this is mostly a novelty thing, I have a windows laptop, so if there's a risk of mangling my mac I'll just get a newer macbook eventually

Is there a way to make an mbr bootcamp partition? if it's doable safely, any resources would be appreciated as I looked online and it's a mess of forum posts of peoples' problems.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it. https://superuser.com/questions/1590339/is-it-possible-to-make-a-mbr-legacy-bootcamp-win-10-from-a-gpt-partitioned-hdd-o

Comment: You question does not make any sense. Explain why you do not just use the Boot Camp Assistant application to install Windows 10 to the internal drive?

Comment: Your question apparently only exists in the title. The body of your post contains no relevant information. The answer to the question is Yes. If more information needed, then edit your question and ask for what you need.

Comment: @David Anderson I'm not an expert on the matter, but I think it will cause problems because my macbook air 2012 is pre eufi, and that results in a broken functionality windows https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250137979?page=15, I tried installing with vm and ssd and both times the graphics card driver update would crash it, no audio, etc, which was fine because that wasn't my internal, but I don't want to mess with my main mac drive and have that ruined, so unless I know it will work differently with bootcamp assistant on the internal drive I'm hesitant to risk it.

Comment: @David Anderson the body of my post is asking for resources to make a legacy partition, if the answer is yes I would appreciate a link or something because I couldn't find anything, I edited to ask the question again in the body of the post.

Comment: If you install to the internal drive, the Boot Camp Assistant will make a legacy partition if necessary. If you install to an external drive, the Disk Assistant can be used to make a legacy partition, if necessary. I would image your question must be more complicated that this. Should I assume you are trying to install Windows 10 to BIOS boot on a legacy MBR partitioned external USB SSD?

Comment: Originally I tried to follow recent guides that were complex processes for getting windows 10 onto ssd, and doing that would probably work well for 2013+ macbooks but didn't work for mine, then I learned about legacy and efi and gpt and mbr, and got a little confused, I have a guid gpt apfs drive, if it can create the legacy mbr partition and boot from there that's great, when I tried to do that in parallels it said incompatible partition error of some kind and wouldn't work, so I guess the only way to know is to try, but I've read posts about bootcamp messing up systems so I'm a little wary

Comment: I would prefer to run it from legacy MBR partition external usb ssd if possible, but I have room on internal drive, so if that's the only way, I'll do that, as long as I get audio/drivers working through legacy, because the efi mode was very broken.

Comment: Have you successfully used the Boot Camp Assistant to create the Windows 10 USB flash drive installer yet? If not, this would be a good place to start.

Comment: I loaded the bootcamp drivers to a usb drive to install on my failed ssd, I think I'm going to try internal, it will be faster anyway and no plugging, unplugging of drives which could get annoying.

Comment: Using the Boot Camp Assistant to install to the internal drive is the easiest way to get Windows 10. After installing Windows 10, run Apple Software Update from Windows 10 to get the latest updates. You probably will get a update to Boot Camp 6 or newer.

Comment: @David Anderson thanks for the help, went through bootcamp assistant and it installed fine on internal drive.

Answer (score 1):

Using the boot camp assistant, loading a usb 2.0 usb stick with the iso and drivers, partitioning the drive in boot camp assistant, then letting it reboot into the usb 2.0 installed windows fine on a 2012 macbook air with all windows functionality.

no need to mess around with efi and weird workarounds to get audio and having screwy drivers.